# Log user activities in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where there are two types of user currently, Admin and Vendor, and i want to log their activities like

```
"TestAdmin" viewed transaction
"TestAdmin" added a new vendor
"TestAdmin" edited a Transaction
"TestVendor" added a new Transaction
"TestAdmin" approved Transaction 
"TestAdmin" rejected Transaction 
etc...
```

where "TestAdmin" is an admin and "TestVendor" is a vendor

But i m not sure what approach i should follow

I m thinking of this

Adding an Activity table in DB with following fields

```
user_id 
browser
session_id
ip_address
action
params
```

and call

```
before_filter :record_activity
```

to record all activities

but not sure how to create messages like above

Also i want to figure out if any error occurs and when and why, so for this i take browser fields to figure out whether code doesn't work in IE etc. but this is only one error track field.

Please help and guide to some nice way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok this is what i did...

First create table

```
create_table "activity_logs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "user_id"
    t.string "browser"
    t.string "ip_address"
    t.string "controller"
    t.string "action"
    t.string "params"
    t.string "note"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

created function in application controller

```
def record_activity(note)
    @activity = Activity_Log.new
    @activity.user = current_user
    @activity.note = note
    @activity.browser = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    @activity.ip_address = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    @activity.controller = controller_name 
    @activity.action = action_name 
    @activity.params = params.inspect
    @activity.save
end
```

then call above function from any controller needed
like this....

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
      load_and_authorize_resource

      # POST /accounts
      # POST /accounts.json
     def create
       @account = Account.new(params[:account])
       respond_to do |format|
       if @account.save
        record_activity("Created new account") #This will call application controller  record_activity
        format.js { head :ok }
      else
       format.js { render json: @account.errors, :error => true, :success => false }
      end
    end
  end
```

Hence problem solved......

Thanks all for all their help....

Comment: I like this solution. Great idea, thanks. I also added an object field and I serialize the object `to_json` so I can see the state change, as well as view items that were destroyed!

Comment: I have to say it's obviously coupled. It's OK for small projects, but it will cause serious problems as your projects grows bigger and bigger.

Comment: So, how you viewed the activity after that? did you use a specific graph for that.
Also, it may be useful to add browser type in your activity. i'm using browser gem to see that

Answer (score 8):

There are couple of plugins in rails to implement this kind of functionality model-wise. I used [acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited) which fulfilled my requirement.

I got to know about one more [record_activities](https://github.com/grosser/record_activities), but don't know more about it. Hope it may help to you!

Comment: I used acts_as_audited and it save data for user modal nicely when edited a user information but when edited Transaction it doesn't save any thing in audtis table. In both modal class i include "acts_as_audited :protect => false", any diea? Also how to use this in non-restful controllers?

Comment: And actually i want to record each action in audit table not onlt create and update, like "Admin view Transaction" etc..

Comment: Use acts_as_audited then use a filter in your controllers to add your own records to acts_as_audited's audit trail.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to have these fields on your "Activity" DB:

```
model = name of the model ex. "Vendor", "Transaction"
user_id = id of user
belongsTo = id of user that own the action/created the action etc..
action = name of the action
```

and on your "Activity Model" add a function

```
log_activity(model, user_id, belongsTo, action)
 log = Activity.new
 log.model = model
 log.user_id = user_id
 log.belongsTo = belongsTo
 log.action = action
 log.save
end

then in you other models that you want to log add callbacks like:
before_create :log
before_update :log
before_destroy :log


def log
  Activity.log_activity(self.class, self.user_id, self.belongsTo, self.action)
  # assuming you have this fields on you forms
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set model function where it catches the action like `after_save` ,`after update` and all , if your model is Transaction for the logs table fields can be

```
user_id,
model_name,
action,
ip_address,
session_id,
params
```

Comment: This will work fine if you only want to track changes, but if you want to track what records a user has viewed it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say the answer of @Anil D is obviously coupled. It's OK for small projects, but it will cause serious problems (developing, debugging, maintaining problems) as your projects grows bigger and bigger.

I prefer audited: (https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited), which is a simple & clean solution aiming to user activities only.  It supports Rails3 and associations.